# Meteor: Using If condition to conditionally display templates when user clicks a navigation link

Tags: meteor

I have some templates corresponding to different places. I am using a navigation bar which has links to different places(Manali). I want the corresponding template to be displayed when a particular link is being clicked. I tried assigning id to each anchor link and use it inside the #if loop of the main file. Like below.

```
{{#if equals id 'badrinath'}}

{{> Manali}}  

{{/if}
```

I created a helper function also for the comparison purpose.

```
UI.registerHelper('equals', function(a, b) {
  return a == b; 
});
```

But it isn't working. Can anyone suggest a solution. What property of the link can I capture and use it to display the template accordingly.

Comment: Basically what I want is a functionality like below:<a href="{{> Manali}}">Manali</a>   . But meteor doesn't allow using templates inside HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

You sound to be looking for "routing" functionality.

You might be interested in Iron Router or Flow Router.

You can still implement your functionality without router, as it sounds still a simple situation as described. You are probably just lacking some event listeners to set your `id` variable to the correct value.

Probably something like:

```html
<a data-role="changetemplate" href="targetTemplate">To Target Template</a>
```

```js
var id = new ReactiveVar(); // add the reactive-var package

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  id: function () {
    return id.get();
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  "click a[data-role='changetemplate']": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    id.set(event.currentTarget.href);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry..I forgot to update here.. I had resolved this by using Iron router..Thanks and sorry..:)

Comment: Router.route('/manali', function () {
  this.render('task9');
});